# calculate current streak - sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I hava table with sessions

```
sessions
-----------------
_id | date 
-----------------
1   | 2015-12-25
2   | 2015-12-24
3   | 2015-12-23
4   | 2015-12-22
5   | 2015-12-22
6   | 2015-12-09
7   | 2015-11-04
8   | 2015-05-11
```

Now how to calculate current consecutive streak, 
here in the above table 
current streak is 22 dec- 25 dec -> 4 days

i can remove duplicate dates using distinct command

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date) FROM sessions ORDER BY date DESC;


  date 
  -----------------
  2015-12-25
  2015-12-24
  2015-12-23
  2015-12-22
  2015-12-09
  2015-11-04
  2015-05-11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(JULIANDAY(date)) FROM sessions) -
    COALESCE(
        (
            SELECT MAX(JULIANDAY(t.date))
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT s1.date AS date, s1.date -
                    (SELECT MAX(s2.date)
                     FROM sessions s2
                     WHERE s2.date < s1.date) AS diff
                FROM sessions s1
            ) t
            WHERE t.diff > 1
        ),
        (SELECT MIN(JULIANDAY(date)) FROM sessions)
    )
```

Comment: hi tim, i get 228.0(days between 11/may and 25 dec) as answer when i run the query on the above table data

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT s1.date AS date, s1.date -
        (SELECT MAX(s2.date)
         FROM sessions s2
         WHERE s2.date < s1.date) AS diff
    FROM sessions s1                                  (the diff is always 0)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0bd95/2  i got it working by surrounding them with jullianday func , i have to add 1 to the result of the query

Comment: on mobile device the query runs slow  is there any faster way?

Comment: How many records do you expect to have in production?  We could try to do away with the correlated subquery and replace it with a join, but that would make the query harder to read IMO.